# Angular change the styleUrls value from inside the component

Tags: angular, angular12

I am trying the allow the user the change the styleUrls value at runtime, so Im trying this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  // styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
  styleUrls: [styleUrl]

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  styleUrl = './app.component.css'
  
  ngOnInit() {

    this.styleUrl = './another.css';

  }

}
```

This does not work so is it possible to get something like this to work?

If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work that way. Here is a simple example with two css files and ngClass

Here were are making the component light / dark according to user interaction.

```ts
styleUrls: ['./app.component.light.css', './app.component.dark.css']
```

stylesheet - light(app.component.light.css)

```css
.light.highlight {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

stylesheet - dark(app.component.dark.css)

```css
.dark.highlight {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Now create a base wrapper div for the whole component

```html
<div [ngClass]="isLight ? 'light': 'dark'">
    <!--component content goes here-->
</giv>
```

If you use scss instead, you can use a wrapper just like you used in html

```scss
.light {
    // page styles go here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want can be achieved but not like this.

While you can specify the files and change them at run time, using the [Reflect Metada Api](https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata), this is something quite more advance and would possible lead to other issues with Angular down the line.

If you want to only change the style of a single component, you can achieve this using two scss files and a `HostBinding`.

Here is an example of this:

> Component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: '<button (click)="changeStyle()">Change Style</button>',
  styleUrls: [ './app-one.component.scss', './app-two.component.scss' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements onInit {

  @HostBinding('class') css: string = undefined; 

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.changeStyle();
  }

  changeStyle(): void {
    if (/* condition */) {
      // custom behaviour here
      this.css = 'active';
    } else {
      // custom behaviour here
      this.css = undefined;
    }
  }
}
```

> AppOne css

```css
:host.active {
  button {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

> AppTwo css

```css
:host:not(.active) {
  button {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

Notice that I declare two scss files, one for each type of custom scss that I want.
I also use the [HostBinding](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding) decorator to trigger which style is active.

I don't change the run-time file, instead, I use the css specifity rules to only apply the css that I want. This is done using the `:not()` pseudo-selector, which you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

I would also add, while this is a viable way to implement a changing style in a given component, there are lots of other and better ways to implement themes and the like in an Angular application if that's what you want to achieve.

Comment: I was more looking into something like... if var = something ... styleUrls = 'one.css' else if var = something else .... styleUrls = 'two.css'

Comment: I have update my answer to allow for an if and more custom behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: in your TS code, import the "DomSanitizer" and make a method to change the styleUrl variable:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  styleUrl : string = './app.component.css';
  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  changeCSSStyle() {
    this.styleUrl = (this.styleUrl === './app.component.css') ? './another.css' : './app.component.css';
  }
}
```

Then, in your HTML, invoke the method and have a "<link rel="stylesheet"..." which change at runtime the css (thanks to the dynamically changed styleUrl var):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" [href]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(styleUrl)">
<button (click)="changeCSSStyle()">Change Style</button>
```

Comment: Should it be styleUrls or styleUrl in the changeCSSStyle method?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Ii should be "styleUrl", the same name you use in "sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(styleUrl)" (I just have edited, I had a typo).

Comment: OK, when it loads it reads the css from the first file: ./app.component.scss  but the button (click) does nothing ... changeCSSStyle() {
    this.styleUrl = (this.styleUrl === './app.component.scss') ? './another.scss' : './app.component.scss';
  }

Comment: Here's the full code i'm trying: import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  styleUrl : string = './app.component.scss';
  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  changeCSSStyle() {
    this.styleUrl = (this.styleUrl === './app.component.scss') ? './another.scss' : './app.component.scss';
  }

  ngOnInit() {}


}

Comment: It loads app.component.scss when the app starts but it doesn't read another.scss when I click the button